# IMAP login command - invalid characters?

Tags: imap

I'm trying to log in to an IMAP server in my iPad app. It works for most accounts, but for one particular account, it doesn't.

I can replicate the issue when trying to log into the IMAP server via telnet. Here's what I type (username and password changed to protect the innocent):

```
a1 LOGIN help sm@llworld
a1 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.
```

Yet if I log into this account using Apple Mail, it works fine.

My only guess: is there something going on with the "@" character in the password? Do I need to escape it (somehow)?

Comment: Does the server allow plaintext login? Check the response to `CAPABILITY` to see if `LOGINDISABLED` is included.

Comment: Oops, just noticed that you said it works for other accounts. Try putting the password in "quotes".

Comment: Quotes don't help, sadly.

Comment: Try using Wireshark to capture what Apple Mail is sending.

Answer (score 1):

Very sorry, but it turned out that this was a false alarm. Dumb problem that isn't instructive and that I won't outline here.

Regardless, encapsulating username and password in quotes is obviously a good idea. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score -1):

keep the password in double quotes... also try using the entire mail id like xyz@gmail.com
I have designed an IMAP server for a mailer domain and also the data migration tools from different mail providers and its always better to pass the passwords in double quotes for the special characters like \ @ # $ alsways break the functionality.